# C++ detection idiom failure with inheritance

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming, sfinae, template-argument-deduction

The below code fails to compile.  For some reason inheriting from `HasFoo` causes `IsWrapper` to fail.  It has something to do with the `friend` function `foo()` because inheriting from other classes seems to work fine.  I don't understand why inheriting from `HasFoo` causes the detection idiom to fail.

What is the proper way to detect `WithFoo` as a `Wrapper`?

https://godbolt.org/z/VPyarN

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template<typename TagType, typename ValueType>
struct Wrapper {
  ValueType V;
};

// Define some useful metafunctions.

template<typename Tag, typename T>
T BaseTypeImpl(const Wrapper<Tag, T> &);

template<typename T>
using BaseType = decltype(BaseTypeImpl(std::declval<T>()));

template<typename Tag, typename T>
Tag TagTypeImpl(const Wrapper<Tag, T> &);

template<typename T>
using TagType = decltype(TagTypeImpl(std::declval<T>()));

// Define VoidT.  Not needed with C++17.
template<typename... Args>
using VoidT = void;

// Define IsDetected.
template<template <typename...> class Trait, class Enabler, typename... Args>
struct IsDetectedImpl
  : std::false_type {};

template<template <typename...> class Trait, typename... Args>
struct IsDetectedImpl<Trait, VoidT<Trait<Args...>>, Args...>
  : std::true_type {};

template<template<typename...> class Trait, typename... Args>
using IsDetected = typename IsDetectedImpl<Trait, void, Args...>::type;

// Define IsWrapper true if the type derives from Wrapper.

template<typename T>
using IsWrapperImpl =
  std::is_base_of<Wrapper<TagType<T>, BaseType<T>>, T>;

template<typename T>
using IsWrapper = IsDetected<IsWrapperImpl, T>;

// A mixin.

template<typename T>
struct HasFoo {
  template<typename V,
           typename std::enable_if<IsWrapper<T>::value &&
                                   IsWrapper<V>::value>::type * = nullptr>
  friend void foo(const T &This, const V &Other) {
    std::cout << typeid(This).name() << " and " << typeid(Other).name()
              << " are wrappers\n";
  }
};

template<typename Tag>
struct WithFoo : public Wrapper<WithFoo<Tag>, int>,
                 public HasFoo<WithFoo<Tag>> {};

int main(void) {
  struct Tag {};

  WithFoo<Tag> WrapperFooV;

  // Fails.  Why?
  static_assert(IsWrapper<decltype(WrapperFooV)>::value,
                "Not a wrapper");

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ok, I think this is as minimal as I can make it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't understand why inheriting from `HasFoo` causes the detection idiom to fail.

Isn't completely clear to me also but surely a problem is that you use `IsWrapper<T>` inside the body of `HasFoo<T>` and, when you inherit `HasFoo<WithFoo<Tag>>` from `WithFoo<Tag>` you have that `WithFoo<Tag>` is incomplete when you check it with `IsWrapper`.

A possible solution (I don't know if acceptable for you) is define (and SFINAE enable/disable) `foo()` outside `HasFoo`.

I mean... try rewriting `HasFoo` as follows

```
template <typename T>
struct HasFoo {
  template <typename V>
  friend void foo(const T &This, const V &Other);
};
```

and defining `foo()` outside

```
template <typename T, typename V>
std::enable_if_t<IsWrapper<T>::value && IsWrapper<V>::value>
      foo(const T &This, const V &Other) {
  std::cout << typeid(This).name() << " and " << typeid(Other).name()
            << " are wrappers\n";
}
```

> What is the proper way to detect WithFoo as a Wrapper?

Sorry but your code is too complicated for me.

I propose the following (simpler, I hope) alternative

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template<typename TagType, typename ValueType>
struct Wrapper {
  ValueType V;
};

template <typename T1, typename T2>
constexpr std::true_type IW_helper1 (Wrapper<T1, T2> const &);

template <typename T>
constexpr auto IW_helper2 (T t, int) -> decltype( IW_helper1(t) );

template <typename T>
constexpr std::false_type IW_helper2 (T, long);

template <typename T>
using IsWrapper = decltype(IW_helper2(std::declval<T>(), 0));

template <typename T>
struct HasFoo {
  template <typename V>
  friend void foo(const T &This, const V &Other);
};

template <typename T, typename V>
std::enable_if_t<IsWrapper<T>::value && IsWrapper<V>::value>
      foo(const T &This, const V &Other) {
  std::cout << typeid(This).name() << " and " << typeid(Other).name()
            << " are wrappers\n";
}

template<typename Tag>
struct WithFoo : public Wrapper<WithFoo<Tag>, int>,
                 public HasFoo<WithFoo<Tag>> {};

int main () {
  struct Tag {};

  WithFoo<Tag> WrapperFooV;

  static_assert(IsWrapper<decltype(WrapperFooV)>::value,
                "Not a wrapper");
}
```